# SciFi bounty Hunter with sonic ring grenade

Tags: story-identification, choose-your-own-adventure

Trying desperately to find a book from my childhood.

The only details I can remember:

1. Choose your own adventure with several endings
2. SciFi setting
3. Male protagonist who is a bounty hunter, has many gadgets including a sonic grenade in the shape of a ring that he wears
4. Chases some large alien creature this is naturally very dangerous
5. Book isn't older then 2004

Vaguely remember the colours on the cover were black and green although I'm pretty unsure on that one

Comment: CYOA space bounty hunter book; https://fightingfantasy.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Strider_(book)

Comment: There's also a lot about this that matches https://fightingfantasy.fandom.com/wiki/Appointment_with_F.E.A.R._(book) . The book itself predates 2004, but reprinted editions wouldn't have.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

***[Have your own Extraterrestrial Adventure](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Have-your-own-extra-terrestrial-adventure/dp/0099307006)*** by Douglas Hill

This is the first of three books featuring Del Curb, interstellar bounty hunter, who uses various gadgets built into jewellery, including a sonic grenade ring.  (The next two books - *The Fraxilly Fracas* and *The Colloghi Conspiracy* - are conventional, linear novels aimed at a slightly older audience.)  In the initial book Del is sent to hunt down the large, telepathic alien Rimeq the Renegade.  Unlike most of the Choose Your Own Adventure-type books, *all* of the endings result in Del Curb's success, albeit in very different ways.

> *I had spent a quiet morning fiddling with my new miniature
>   therm-grenade. It had cost more than I could afford, but it was worth
>   it. Though it could turn an ordinary room into a charred ruin, it was
>   small enough to be set into a ring, like a jewel. And that’s where I
>   carried it - along with several other rings - which were only a few of
>   the mini-weapons scattered about my person.*

Most of his ring grenades are "therm-grenades", but he does use a sonic ring grenade at one point:

> *The exter was still 
>   shifting his eyes back and forth between Mala and me, 
>   and didn't notice the small movement when I turned one 
>   of my rings round on my finger. Nor did he notice the 
>   flick of my thumb that sent the jewel from that ring flying 
>   out of its setting.*
>
> *I don't think the exter even saw the tiny object sailing 
>   towards him. But he did see my sudden movement, and 
>   was a millisecond away from firing when my ring-jewel 
>   exploded.*
>
> *The room was filled with the nerve-twisting vibrations 
>   of infra-sonics. They hurt, but they didn't knock me out 
>   - because my sudden movement had been to clap my 
>   hands over my ears, and it's through the ears that sonics 
>   deliver their knock-out punch.*

[image]

Comment: I've taken the liberty of adding a book quote and the front cover of the most common copy.

Comment: The Internet Archive actually has the full text of this book - and reading it, I am absolutely sure this was the book OP was looking for! I may delete my answer after OP accepts this one.

Comment: @Astrid_Redfern - Leave it up. It might help someone looking for a similar property

Comment: @Valorum extraordinarily fast edit after I posted - thanks for the cover and quotes, I was posting from 30 year old memories and a quick Google.

Comment: OMG THANK YOU SO MUCH, this is the one!!!

Answer (score 2):

I think this may be the Fighting Fantasy gamebook [Appointment with F.E.A.R](https://fightingfantasy.fandom.com/wiki/Appointment_with_F.E.A.R._(book)). It's not a perfect match for OP's description, but I'll explain why I think it may still be the one.

- *"Choose your own adventure with several endings"*. It is indeed a CYOA-style book, with four "good" endings and at least two "bad" endings.
- *"SciFi setting"* It seems to be the same sort of "near future with some present-day tech and some futuristic sci-fi tech" setting as the Marvel and DC universes.
- *"Male protagonist"*. This one's a bit iffy. It's never actually revealed whether the protagonist is male or female (or non-binary!). This is to allow the reader to decide for themselves without it having an effect on gameplay.
- *"who is a bounty hunter"*. This one's *really* iffy. You're actually playing a superhero, not a bounty hunter. During the course of play, you receive text messages about criminals on the loose, sent to you by "Gerry the Grass", and you need to choose which of these to respond to as there's just too much crime in Titan City to deal with it all. So it does play somewhat as if you were a superpowered bounty hunter.
- *"has many gadgets including a sonic grenade in the shape of a ring that he wears"*. At the start of the book, you need to choose between four different superpowers. [One of the choices](https://fightingfantasy.fandom.com/wiki/Enhanced_Technological_Skill) gives you access to a utility belt containing LOTS AND LOTS of gadgets! OP's description might match the "Sonic Confuser" device from this list. And there's a sort of anti-sonic weapon too, the "Directional Sound Neutralizer".
- *"Chases some large alien creature this is naturally very dangerous"* Another point that's a bit iffy - you're actually chasing a mad scientist who's turned himself into the very dangerous "Titanium Cyborg". That said, there *might* have been a large alien creature as one of the umpteen lesser antagonists prior to encountering him.
- *"Isn't older than 2004"* Now, this one's also a bit iffy. The original edition came out long before 2004. However, the Wizard Books edition was published in April 2004.
- *"Vaguely remember the colours on the cover were black and green although I'm pretty unsure on that one"*. Green and black are the predominant colours on the cover, although there are smaller areas of other colours, as you can see:

[image: Front cover of 2004 Wizard Books edition]

[image: Front cover of original edition]

Finally, it was a really, really fun superhero parody with lots of references to both Marvel and DC, and I can **DEFINITELY** see why OP would want to track it down!